# Sending message from super class to subclass

Tags: objective-c

I have a base class lets say `BaseClass` which does some logic and handles gestures. I have another class `FooBarClass` which provides the view and is also a subclass of `BaseClass, (FooBar : Base)`.

I know that I can call methods in super class by `super methodName`. I am stuck in a situation now, all of views are designed like these and now I need to pass message from `FooBar` to `Base`.

Is that possible ? If so how ? Should I be using `NSNotifications` or is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: By overriding the methods in `FooBar` you can actually return data to parent class. Just like data source.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I guess OP is asking the opposite of that if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating instance of subclass, which in your case is `FooBarClass`, you need not worry about message passing from super class to subclass. With inheritance, whatever properties, methods are exposed in header file (.h) of `BaseClass`, can be accessed from `FooBarClass`. If the methods belonging to `BaseClass` has been overridden in `FooBarClass`, then you have to explicitly make use of `super` otherwise, you can directly call `self`. However, if the properties belonging to `BaseClass` has been overridden in `FooBarClass`, then that variable will be holding the value which has been stored last. That is the reason why usually, properties are never overridden as it gets confusing.

Lastly, there is no need for `NSNotification`.

Ex: BaseClass.h

```
@interface BaseClass : UIView

- (void)runTest;
- (void)sayHi;
- (void)sayHi2;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger commonVar;
@end
```

BaseClass.m

```
- (void)runTest
{
    self.commonVar = 100;
}
- (void)sayHi
{
    NSLog(@"Hi from super");
    NSLog(@"In super variable = %d", self.commonVar);  
}
- (void)sayHi2
{
   NSLog(@"Hi from super2");
}
```

FooBarClass.h

```
@interface FooBaseClass : BaseClass

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger commonVar;
@end
```

FooBarClass.m

```
 - (void)runTest
{
    self.commonVar = 1;
    [super runTest];  // Now, commonVar variable will be holding 100 throughout.
    [super sayHi];
    [super sayHi2];  // Same as next line because there is no sayHi2 overridden.
    [self sayHi2];
    [self sayHi];
}

- (void)sayHi
{
    NSLog(@"Hi from derived");
    NSLog(@"In derived variable = %d", self.commonVar);  
}
```

Hope this answer helps you.